# Execute sql in DB Browser for SQLite can create two tables, but running the javascript code can only get the first table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

When I execute sql in DB Brower, there is no problem creating two tables: user and videoInfo, but when I run the JavaScript code, I can only get the first table: user, could anyone explain what cause this problem? Thank you. The key code is as follows:

```
const db = new DB("sqlitedb3")


   class Db {
    constructor(file) {
        this.db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
        this.createTable()
    }


createTable() {
    const sql = `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
            id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            name text,
            email text UNIQUE,
            user_pass text,
            is_admin integer);

        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "videoInfo" (
            "id"    INTEGER,
            "start" TEXT,
            "end"   TEXT,
            "label" TEXT,
            "imgUrl"    TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY("id")
        ) `
    return this.db.run(sql);
}
```

}

**UPDATE**: I could not figure out the issue above, but this is the way how I deal with it to make it work now:

```
const db = new DB("sqlitedb3")


   class Db {
    constructor(file) {
        this.db = new sqlite3.Database(file);
        this.createTable()
        this.createTable2()
    }


createTable1() {
    const sql = `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
            id integer PRIMARY KEY,
            name text,
            email text UNIQUE,
            user_pass text,
            is_admin integer); `
    return this.db.run(sql);
}

    createTable2() {
    const sql = `
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "videoInfo" (
            "id"    INTEGER,
            "start" TEXT,
            "end"   TEXT,
            "label" TEXT,
            "imgUrl"    TEXT,
            PRIMARY KEY("id")
        ) `
    return this.db.run(sql);
}
```

}

Comment: By "get the first table" do you mean that you log into the database and can only see the `user` table?

Comment: Hi Nick, yes, so there is only one table which is user in the database